# Using FTP with a Shared Windows Folder

Tags: windows, virtualbox, fstab, ftp, chmod

I started to use Ubuntu two weeks ago, I still have some difficulty in understanding the whole world of Linux.

I'm in front of the following scenario:

I have a Windows computer running 12.04 in a VirtualBox, I've installed in Ubuntu `samba` and `proftpd`, because I've limited the Ubuntu HD to 8GB. I had the idea to use a shared Windows folder to use as my main FTP storage place.

In `/etc/fstab` I've added the following line

```
//192.168.0.10/D$/ /mnt/FTP cifs user,umask=0022,gid=0,uid=0,suid,username="####",password=##### 0 0
```

I can mount my partition with `mount /mnt/FTP`, I can access, but I cannot create anything in the directory.

The permission of the directory is `dr-xr-xr-x 0 root root`.

I want to have the permissions, but how can I do it?

---

Was my fault to not test direct by Linux before posting, I've verified if I could create or change anything direct in ssh while I was writing, first of all I've tested using FTP.

I've tried right now to `chmod -R 777 /mnt/FTP`, and I got permission denied error, I'm logged in my virtual Linux with ssh.

---

I've unmounted the `/mnt/FTP` and I could `chmod 777` the folder, but the permission of the containing files inside the `/mnt/FTP` still `dr-xr-xr-x`.

And can't change their permissions. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Directory permissions are set with the CHMOD command.  Here's a wiki article on it - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod - There's some helpful commands and some explanation on what you're seeing when you see dr-xr-xr-x or any variation thereof.

Comment: Why are you using the word FTP at all? It's a Samba share and has nothing to do with FTP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a new user and Linux is a bit complicated yet to me. I think I found the solution
`dir_mode=0777`, `file_mode=0777` in the `/etc/fstab`.

My problem is now solved. The problem was the permission in the fstab.